# Is there any method to analyze data from fire protection events?

Tags: cartography, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I want to analyze data from events in fire protection a create some illustration of maps. 
In short: my task is to find methods for data visualization. Data are represented by point layer (each event is localized and except the coordinates, each event has some information in attribute table).

Can you tell me some methods I can use (except classic chloropleth map and diagram map)? I analyzed data with kernel density tool, or I have used "count points in polygon" tool from Hawths Analysis tools for creating cartogram maps. I used this tool for Quadrat Analysis too - creating vector grid (polygons) over the extent and counting the events in each polygon (quadrat).

Last method was line diagram map (creating buffer from line data and counting points in each polygon segment of buffer, this information was necessary to visualize events that happened on the roads.

Is there some other method or tool I can use?

Thanks for help

Comment: First you need to ask yourself "what do I want to find out from this data set?"

Comment: My primary task is not analyzing data and finding out some facts, but showing some methods, that can be applied on this data. (this data will be used as part of web application database for map visualization and publishing)

Comment: So edit your title to reflect this. My point still stands, any visualisation's purpose is to tell a story, and unless you know the plot how can you tell the story properly?